# Visual Studio Code HTML not reading ™ or ©

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

How could people have been using this code editor for HTML when it butchers this © and this ™?  When I edit the page any © symbol will look like a triangle with a question mark and when the page is saved they will look like this ï¿½.

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem

Comment: How can I get it to work? Is there a plugin?

Comment: Open the file in another editor and set the correct encodind. Notepad++ can do this for example

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I do not have Notepad++. Can this be done in Visual Studio Code or Expression Web?  And what would the correct encodind be?  Also this is now only happening with the © symbol.  VSC is no longer effecting the ™.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
&copy;
```

it will be displayed in your browser as: ©

Same goes for:

```
&trade;
```

it will be displayed in your browser as: ™

Answer (score 0):

You can also use HTML name codes or decimal codes to print the character:

```html
<!-- the copyright sign (name code / decimal code) -->
&copy; &#169;

<!-- the trademark sign (name code / decimal code) -->
&trade; &#8482;
```

Using this name codes or decimal codes you can avoid encoding issues.

> You can find more characters on [this Character Entity Reference Chart](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).